# List custom post types on a category page divided by its subcategories

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In Wordpress how do I list custom post types on a category page divided by the subcategory the posts are in?

My example:
I have the custom taxonomy advertisements. I also have a custom post type called advertisement.

Category structure:

- Footer
- Sidebar
- Sponsors page

  - Gold
  - Silver
  - Bronze

If I go to myurl.com/sponsors-page/ it will display all the ads in the gold, silver and bronze category. So far so good. But I want it to display them in order of the subcategories and echo the subcategory name. For example:

- Gold

  - Ad 1
  - Ad 2
- Silver

  - Ad 3
  - Ad 4
- Bronze

  - Ad 5
  - Ad 6

How do I accomplish that? Feel free to question my approach, I'm new to Wordpress.

I feel like this is probably a duplicate, but trust me when I say that I´ve tried to search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just started with Wordpress as well, but here's what I think you want to do.

```
// get available taxonomies
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies ( (object) array ('post_type' => 'subcategory' ));

// loop all taxonomies
foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) { 

    // Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );

    // loop through the terms
    foreach( $terms AS $term ) {
        // get posts
        $posts = new WP_Query( "taxonomy=$taxonomy&term=$term->slug" );

        // check for posts
        if ( $posts-> have_posts() ) {
            // how your header (gold,silver,bronze)
            echo '<h2>' . $term-> name . '</h2>';               

            // loop through posts
            while ( $posts-> have_posts() ) {
                // get the post
                $posts-> the_post();

                // show your ad
                echo $posts-> post-> post_content;

                // Update temporary value
                $posts_count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers! Will give you the bounty when I'm able too. For future reference I also added "array('parent' => get_queried_object()->term_id)" to the get_terms so that I only get the childs of the current term. Again, thank you.

Comment: @JohanDavidsson how exactly did you make the addition?